# Node Js | Как найти определенный объект

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Имеется массив в json

```
[{
    "id":1, 
    "users":{
        "newId":{"bet":0},
        "newId2":{"bet":1},
        "newId3":{"bet":1}
    }
}]
```

Как мне найти юзеров со ставкой 1 и добавить им +10 еще?

Answer (score 0):

1. Очень странно, что в `users` — объект объектов, а не массив объектов.
2. Код будет работать, только для вашего приведённого `json`.

```js
const $json = '[{"id":1,"users":{"newId":{"bet":0},"newId2":{"bet":1},"newId3":{"bet":1}}}]';
let js_parse = JSON.parse($json);

for(index in js_parse) {
  if(!!js_parse[index].users.newId.bet){
    js_parse[index].users.newId.bet  += 10;
  }
  if(!!js_parse[index].users.newId2.bet){
    js_parse[index].users.newId2.bet  += 10;
  }
  if(!!js_parse[index].users.newId3.bet){
    js_parse[index].users.newId3.bet  += 10;
  }
}

console.log(js_parse);
```